# Recursion to output possible outcomes of N number of coin flips

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use recursion to output the possible outcomes of N number of coin flips. For instance, if I flip a coin 3 times the possible outputs could be TTT, TTH, THT, THH, HTT, HTH, HHT, and HHH. I'm not looking for an answer but a push in the right direction. Would this be best done with a character array? Or assigning H and T integer values?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since it can only ever be heads or tails, you could use a boolean value. This would be more efficient for memory and will also help avoid the need for error checking. But there is no single way of doing it, experiment and see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

I would say integers. Look up permutations and simple combinatorics if you​haven't already.  Remember, recursion operates on the principal of breaking a big problem into smaller ones.